# Oddity when disabling Windows Time service on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, services

I want to disable time synchronization on Windows XP. To do so, I have disabled the Windows Time (w32time) service. However, one of my testers noticed that the "Automatically synchronize time..." checkbox on the Date/Time control panel was still checked.

The workstations in this case will be running an application in kiosk mode, so no users will ever see that control panel or be able to change the settings. It will also never be on a domain. Does that checkbox in control panel do anything if w32time is disabled, or is it just a visual oddity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service is disabled, time will not sync.

However, the proper way to configure Windows Time Service is using the [w32tm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx) command line utility